# not load data from api in rapidapi flutter App

Tags: flutter, rapidapi, tasty

i need to load the data to my application

when i retrive from this link https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums its work
but when i use rapid api not load data
the problem is in the connection to the server or not

** the code file here  **

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  var uri = Uri.https('yummly2.p.rapidapi.com', '/feeds/list',
      {"limit": "18", "start": "0", "tag": "list.recipe.popular"});

  final response = await http
      .get(uri,
      headers:{
        "x-rapidapi-key": "my api key",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "yummly2.p.rapidapi.com",
        "useQueryString": "true"
      }
      );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.map((data) => Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Recipes');
  }
}

class Data {
  //final int image;
 // final int rating;
  final String name;

  Data({ required this.name});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      //image: json['thumbnail_url'],
      //rating: json['user_ratings']['score'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass wrong link in Uri.https(). Take an example below for how to pass API link of rapidapi

```
Uri.parse(
      "$pre_url/everything?q=apple&from=2022-09-26&to=2022-09-26&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=$api_key"
```